# Autowalk going in opposite direction unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

https://github.com/JuppOtto/Google-Cardboard/blob/master/Autowalk.cs

Is going in opposite direction and sometimes will go in the right direction.?

Help me out to fix it to go in the correct direction

Here is the code involved:

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>(); 
moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head.c‌​amera.transform.position);
if (controller.isGrounded)
{ 
    moveDirection *= speed; 
} 
controller.Move(moveDirectionspeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The movement is always in the opposite direction.

Now i tired in increasing the speed in negative direction now its moving front but its getting pulled from the left I am clueless.

Comment: Please can you post the lines of code that are involved and where it is going wrong.

Comment: CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
  moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head.camera.transform.position);
  if (controller.isGrounded) {

   moveDirection *= speed;
   
  }
  controller.Move(moveDirection*speed * Time.deltaTime); Here is the code Jamie the movement is always in the opposite direction. Now i tired in increasing the speed in negative direction now its moving front but its getting pulled from the left I am clueless Please Help

Comment: I fixed it finally here is the code for autowalk. In the update use this code                                                                                                    Vector3 fwd = Cam_pos.transform.TransformDirection     (Vector3.forward);
  RaycastHit hit;
  if (Physics.Raycast (Cam_pos.transform.position, fwd, out hit, 10)) 
  {
   Debug.DrawLine (Cam_pos.transform.position, hit.point, Color.cyan);
   if(hit.distance <= 5.0 && hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Untagged") 
   {
    transform.position=Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,hit.point,speed*Time.deltaTime);
   }
  }